# Why do my VS Code keybindings change when I open IntelliJ IDEA projects?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

In VS Code, my keybindings change when I open a project.
I have enabled the "Default" profile in File > Preferences > Profile but when opening a project  (IntelliJ project) the keybindings change.

The bindings change in all other instance until I have closed the instances and completely reopen VS Code.

For example when I open VS Code without a project (workspace folder), I can create a new file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
When I open a project it changes to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

How can I disable / control this behavior?
Why does this happen?

Comment: Does the project file (<name>.code-workspace) specify custom settings?

Comment: Do the keybinding changes reflect in the keyboard shortcut editor UI?

Comment: I have found the issue now. It was an extension (IntelliJ IDEA keybindings) which changes the shortcuts when opening idea projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have the [`k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings) extension installed. If you want to disable this behaviour, you can disable the extension. You can disable it globally, or on specific workspaces.